# How to run a tamper monkey script after a specific page shows up?

Tags: javascript, json, tampermonkey

I have made a tampermonkey script by getting help from StackOverflow that reloads the web page until a specific word is found. The script is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var find = "News"; // Change this to find a different string

if($('*:contains("' + find + '")').length > 0)
{
    alert("Found: " + find);
}
else
{
    location.reload();
}
```

});

The problem is that the word I want to find appears on a web page after I click a button on the web page although the URL doesn't changes after clicking the button. In easy words I want to create a script that clicks the button first then searches for the word and if the word isn't found, it refreshes the page then clicks the button again and searches for the word until it's found.

PS :- That button element's class is

> btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block

Answer (score 0):

Call the button's [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method before checking the page for the word.

```
$('.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block').click();
```

Keep in mind this will click *every* button on the page with those four classes on them. If there's only one, that's fine, but if there's more you'll need to specify which one using an additional [selector](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/).